# "return Json(jsonData)" vs "return content (jsonData, "application/json")"

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I have this code inside an ASP.NET MVC 5 action method, which serializes an object as JSON using Newtonsoft package:

```
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

And I can return the above JSON using this return statement:

```
return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Or using this return statement:

```
return Content(output, "application/json");
```

So are there really any differences between the two methods `return Json(jsonData)` vs `return content (jsonData, "application/json")` ?

And which one should we use to return the already serialized json object?

Now when I call the action method from Firefox, I will get this json in case I use `return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`:

[image]

while I will get this json (which seems to be the accurate one) when using `return Content(output, "application/json");`:

[image]

It seems the json I will get when using `return Content(output, "application/json");` is the accurate one, while using `return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` will return string that is not be understandable by Firefox?

Thanks

Comment: If you already serialized it to a json string, passing that string into `Json` will serialize it again. With `return Json` you would pass in your object to be serialized and dont need to serialize it first [system.web.mvc.controller.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Comment: @RyanWilson ok so since i am already serializing the object so i need to use `return Content(output,"application/json");`?

Comment: thats your choice, either serialize it and pass it with `Content` or dont serialize it and pass your object into `Json` and let it serialize it for you

Comment: @RyanWilson i prefer to use NewtonSoft package instead of relying on the built-in JSON serialization .. keeping in mind that i am coming from MVC-2 & MVc-3

Comment: Then you have your answer